# Adding Apply function results to the original df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

```
df
date         fruit      var1    var2
2010-01-01    apple      40      30
2010-01-01    banana     40      30
...
```

I want to add as a new column, called avg, the results from the apply function below to the original df, ideally without having to create a variable called test.

```
test = df.groupby('date').apply(some_function, "var1", "var2")
print(test)
date
2010-01-01    0.744337
2010-01-02    0.7445
```

Expected Output:

```
date         fruit      var1    var2      avg
2010-01-01    apple      40      30     0.744337
2010-01-01    banana     40      30     0.744337
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If is not possible modify function use:

```
df = df.join(test.rename('avg'), on='date')
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way without creating test in the first place?

Comment: @arv - Can you add `some_function` to question?